Use algebraic topology to maximize the cardinality of a subset in a vector space (or module) with chain complex constraints
Given a vector space $V=\mathbb{F}_2^{2n}$, consider a subset $E=\{a_j\} \subset V$ consisting of  $k$ elements. Construct a chain complex $C_{*}(E)$ as follows:

0-chains (Single vertex): $C_0(E) = \mathbb{Z}_2$.
1-chains (Edges): $ C_1(E)$ is the free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-module generated by elements $ [a_j] $, corresponding to elements $ a_j \in E $.
2-chains (Faces): $ C_2(E) $ is the free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-module generated by pairs $ [a_i|a_j] $ of edges $ a_i, a_j \in E $ such that the symplectic pairing condition $ a_i^T \Lambda a_j = 0 \mod 2 $ is satisfied, where $\Lambda$ is the symplectic form.
3-chains (Volumes): $ C_3(E) $ is the free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-module generated by triples $ [a_i|a_j|a_k] $ of edges $ a_i, a_j, a_k \in E $ such that they form a connected triple of faces (i.e., $ [a_i|a_j] $, $ [a_j|a_k] $, and $ [a_i|a_k] $ all exist in $ C_2(E) $).

Define boundary maps $ \partial: C_p(E) \rightarrow C_{p-1}(E) $ for $ p = 1, 2, 3 $ in the usual manner (i.e., by taking linear combinations of the faces of simplices).
The cobounary operator is defined by $dc(x)=c\partial x$ where $c\in C^{n}(E)$ and $x \in C_{n+1}(E)$.
Given the following constraints:

The 2-cochain $ \beta $ satisfies $ d\beta = 0 $ meaning it is a 2-cocycle.
$ [\beta] = 0 $.

What is the maximum possible dimension $ k $ of the subset $ E $ such that these constraints on the cochain complex are satisfied?

My sketch/attempt at the solution to find a lower bound
Divide the set $E=\cup_j E_j$ into isotropic subspaces each consisting of a maximum of $n$ elements that all satisfy the symplectic pairing condition such that for every $u,v \in E_j$ we have $u^T\Lambda v=0$.
It is possible to construct a valid chain complex using a subset of vectors consisting of $2n+1$ elements such that for every element $a_j,a_k\in E$ we have $a_j^T\Lambda a_k=1$. In the chain complex structure, these are each connected by faces.
Consider the case that we have $E$ maximally isotropic. Then we have $n$ elements that each satisfy the isotropic condition. This is not a problem for the other conditions but it may not be maximal.
By varying over the different combinations we see that the best case is when we have $2n+1$ sets $E_j$ consisting of a single element. I.e., the maximally nonisotropic set.
To prove this is the maximum possible size of such a set such, we use that for every element $a_j,a_k\in E$ we have $a_j^T\Lambda a_k=1$. If we now have a set with $2n+2$ elements, we must have one element $u$ such that $u^T\Lambda a_k=0$ for some other $a_k \in E$.
This means the max size of such a set is at least 2n+1. I.e., it is a lower bound for the maximum size of the set. It does not prove that other types of subsets could not exist that do not take this form.

My question
Is there a way to find the maximum possible size of the subset (e.g., by using algebraic topology techniques)?
Note: I would also like to extend the proof to the module $V=\mathbb Z_d^{2n}$, where $\mathbb Z_d=(\mathbb Z)/(d\mathbb Z)$ the ring of integers mod $d$ for arbitrary $d\in\{3,4,5,\dots\}$; ideally a solution should be possible to extend to that case (unlike the proof of the lower bound I give above).

I don't think I understand the notation $(\Bbb Z_d)^{2n}$. I would read it as $(\Bbb Z/d\Bbb Z)^{2n}$ but this is never a field (i.e. 'vector space' might be confusing, I suggest 'module' instead)

@FShrike you are correct, it is a module unless d=2

Ah, when you said “defined over” I thought you meant $V$ is a module over the ring $R=(\Bbb Z_2)^{2n}$. Do you instead mean $V=(\Bbb Z_2)^{2n}$ as a module/vector space over $\Bbb Z_2$? This is confusing. Even if $d=2$, $(\Bbb Z_2)^{2n}$ is not a field.

@FShrike sorry for the bad notation. I mean $\mathbb F_2$ for the vector space. Vectors are length 2n with element values 0,1. The extension is that the vectors can take elements with values 0,1,...,d

The first sentence of your question still doesn't make sense: There are no vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_2^{2n}$ because $\mathbb{F}_2^{2n}$ is not a field. Do you mean to say "module," or do you mean something else?

@BenSteffan I meant the vector space is defined over $\mathbb F_2$. Therefore it is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_2^{2n}$. So $V=\mathbb F_2^{2n}$ should just be the space of $2n$-dimensional binary vectors.
